# Extracting a set of lines from a text file

Tags: python, dataframe, python-re

I have a set of text files, such as https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/A0R4Q6.txt

I'm trying to write a function that takes a UniProt ID as an input and then outputs a dataframe (preferably that I can use as an input for scikit-learn?) with the following format (only comma-delimited for clarity):

```
UniProt-ID,Position,AA   
A0R4Q6,1,M
A0R4Q6,2,T
A0R4Q6,3,Q
```

This is what I'm currently working with:

```
def get_features(ID):
    featureList=[]
    #set and open link to uniprot webiste
    link="https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/{}.txt".format(ID) 
    file = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
    #find amino acid sequence
    for line in file:
        nextLine = next(file)
        #print(nextLine)
        if b'SQ' in line:
            print(line)
            #unsure how to extract more than 1 line
            #additionally, the number of lines that
            #I will need will be variable, depending on the protein length
            
            #this is what I think the extracted lines put into a string will look like
            aaSeq='MTQMLTRPDV\tDLVNGMFYAD\tGGAREAYRWM\tRANEPVFRDR\tNGLAAATTYQ\tAVLDAERNPE\nLFSSTGGIRP\tDQPGMPYMID'
            #remove \t and \n characters
            ActualSeq=re.sub('\s+', '', aaSeq)
            print(ActualSeq)
    #now iterate through the string to create dataframe?
    p=1
    for i in ActualSeq:
        featureList.append([ID,p,i])
        p+=1
    return featureList
seq=get_features('A0R4Q6')
print(seq)
```

I have two issues:

1. searching for b'SQ' does not return anything, but this syntax does work if I search for b'ID' or b'FT' etc. Any ideas why it's not recognizing the 'SQ'?
2. I'm not sure how to get this for-loop to return all the lines following the 'SQ' line until the last line containing the '//' and compress this into a string.

Additionally, is this method of putting the 'data frame' into a list of tuples the most efficient, or should I do something completely different? The end goal is to use this dataframe as an input for a SciKit-Learn Random Forest.

TIA!

Comment: You are skipping half of the data with line `nextLine = next(file)`, because you are advancing `file` iterator in that line

Comment: @fdermishin, thank you, fixed!

Answer (score 0):

To get the exact output you requested, try this:

```py
def get_features(ID):
    featureList=[]

    # Set and open link to uniprot webiste
    link="https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/{}.txt".format(ID) 
    file = urllib.request.urlopen(link)

    found_seq = False
    full_sec = ''
    
    # Find amino acid sequence
    for line in file:
      if line.startswith(b'SQ   '):
        found_seq = True
      elif found_seq and line.startswith(b'     '):
        line = ''.join(line.decode("utf-8").split())
        # print(line)
        full_sec += line
      else:
        found_seq = False

    # Enumerate items
    for i, a in enumerate(full_sec):
      featureList.append([ID, i+1, a])
    return featureList


seq = get_features('A0R4Q6')

for item in seq:
  print(item)
```

It will print the following:

```
['A0R4Q6', 1, 'M']
['A0R4Q6', 2, 'T']
['A0R4Q6', 3, 'Q']
['A0R4Q6', 4, 'M']
['A0R4Q6', 5, 'L']
...
```